# RSpec's be_success outputs a new line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This is a mild annoyance I've noticed when running my rspec (v3.3.1) test suite.

For all test cases where I've used the `be_success` matcher, a newline is printed on my terminal. As a result, on running the suite, my terminal looks like this:

```
....*.................
.


.......
..
.
.......................................................F....T
```

Instead of

```
....*...................................................................................F....T
```

which is what I'd like.

I figured `be_success` is the culprit by running my suite with the `--format d` option and noticed that only tests that use be_success, cause a new line to be printed.

I'd like to know if there's a way I can get rid of this without having to replace `be_success` with something like `have_http_status(200)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`be_success` does not normally print lines.  All it does it call `success?`.

My guess is that you've got a `puts` in your `success?` implementation and/or in something `success?` delegates to.  Perhaps from a past debugging session?